# How to extract all characters before digit and expand to another column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Just wondering what I am doing wrong with regex(very new to it).

```
df
             tradingsymbol
0            USDEUR18D21P
1            KNIFY20DEC182700P
```

I am trying to extract all characters before the first digit. And extract the part before it into another column.

I have tried:

```
df['tradingsymbol'].str.extract('^(\D)\d', expand=True)
```

It gives me all `NaN` result.

I have tried a few other expressions and all have either returned `NaN` or given an error about unbalance parenthesis.

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Expected o/p

```
 df
             tradingsymbol          symbol
0            USDEUR18D21P           USDEUR
1            KNIFY20DEC182700P      KNIFY
```

Comment: You need `'^(\D+)'`

Comment: Wow, Thanks. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only capturing a single non-digit with `\D`.  You need a greedy modifier:

```
^(\D+)\d
```